# attempting to register UICollectionViewCell subclass but keep getting "Cannot invoke 'registerClass' with an ..."

Tags: ios, swift, syntax, compilation

I've created a subclass of `UICollectionViewCell` called `Preview` and created a `Preview` cell with the `reuseIdentifier` `PreviewWindow` within a `UICollectionView` in the Storyboard Editor.

I get the error:

> **../ViewController.swift:15:29: Cannot invoke 'registerClass' with an argument list of type '(Preview.Type, forCellWithReuseIdentifier:
>   String)'**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.collectionView.registerClass(Preview.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "PreviewWindow")     
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

           let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Preview", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Preview

        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
}


class Preview: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var bigLabel: UILabel!

}
```

I've also tried the following variation:

```
collectionView.registerClass(NSClassFromString("Preview"),forCellWithReuseIdentifier:"PreviewWindow")
```

But get the same result.

Any help would be amazing!

Comment: please post your full code

Comment: Do you want the AppDelegate.swift as well? I posted the remainder of the code; there's not much to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : and I also use some dummy data

```
class Preview: UICollectionViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var bigLabel: UILabel!
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

var dummydata = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    dummydata = ["we are young","Swift all day ","IOS all day","SWift better than ObjC"]
      }


func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Preview", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! Preview

    cell.bigLabel.text = dummydata[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.dummydata.count
}
 }
```

Comment: I'm not intending to create numerous cells here, but thanks.

Comment: I didn't say that I just wanted to give something g that work

Comment: Indeed it worked, I figured out the issue; collectionView wasn't available in viewDidLoad. I spent a really long time on a silly mistake.. love it when that happens... Thanks anyway. :)